# How to use persian variable in sqlite in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, persian

I create table in android sqlite.
My table is category:

> db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (id_category INTEGER 
>   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,sub INT(5),name VARCHAR ,father INT(5),
>   income_bool INT(1));");

now i create a variable:

> `String a="بنزین"`

I Insert a row Successfully(with Persian name) and show it in listview;

```
> But when i select i have errors: String ROW3 = "SELECT * FROM category
> WHERE name=" + a; 
>Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(ROW3, null);
>cursor.moveToFirst();
>Log.d("ghable vorod be for", "sa");
>for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            Log.d("ghable vorod be for1", "sa");
            cat_id=(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_category"));
            Log.d("ghable vorod be for2", "sa");
        }
```

but  i have this errors in logcat:

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: بنزین
>
> Shutting down VM
>
> thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: بنزین: ,
>   while compiling: SELECT * FROM category WHERE name=بنزین
>
> 09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native
>   Method) 09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:49) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   com.example.hesabdar.New_income.onClick(New_income.java:174) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 09-30 15:28:17.358:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 09-30 15:28:17.358:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-30 15:28:17.358:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-30 15:28:17.358:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   09-30 15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 09-30
>   15:28:17.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28713):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-30 15:33:17.468:
>   I/Process(28713): Sending signal. PID: 28713 SIG: 9

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't include the value directly in your SQL at all. Instead, use *parameterized SQL*, such as:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM category WHERE name=?",
                            new String[] { a });
```

That way:

- You don't need to worry about how non-ASCII should be represented
- You don't need to worry about escaping the data to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Your SQL is easier to read, without all the string concatenation

(In normal JDBC you could set parameters for other data types than String, avoiding conversion issues too - looks like that's not quite available here, but it's a *common* benefit of parameterized SQL.)

Answer (score 2):

For normal string value insertion in database we have a method which appends `'` character at start and end and all the occurence of `'` character is replace by `''`.

```
public String FormatDBString(String StringToFormat)
{           
   if (StringToFormat == null || StringToFormat.equals(""))
    {
        return "'"+ "" + "'";
    }
    else
        return "'" + StringToFormat.replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

and then you can use this function as

```
String ROW3 = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name= " + FormatDBString(a)
```

This function provides usability as we have to write so many SQL and chances of mistakes, SQL injection etc are minimized too.